how to convert string in date format to UNIX time? c++
char sDateAndTime[80];
time_t t;
t = 1643873040;
tm *timeinfo = localtime( &t );
strftime( sDateAndTime, 80, "%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M:%S", timeinfo );
std::cout << sDateAndTime;

i have code which converts unix time to string but i need to convert string to unix time
examples with strPtime are not running and ss >>... also

Stop using "C" use the  header and its facilities

Why did you tag c++-chrono if you're not even using it? :/

If you can't use c++20 and it's expanded Chrono support then the header only library it was based on gives the same functionality in c++17 https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html
